# Obligations of Canadian university hiring remote California worker?

Tags: canada, taxes, employment, california

Asking for a friend. A Canadian university wants to hire me as a remote employee. I'll be working in Los Angeles. My annual salary is $60000 in 2020, and would be more in 2021.

Which of these things is the university liable for?

- Social Security, Medicare, and FUTA
- obligations such as paid sick leave or unpaid time off for pregnancy
- withholding California state income tax? They and I would prefer they withhold Canada federal and provincial tax instead as I have to file a nonresident Canadian return

I have emplyment authorization both in Canada and the US so that will not be an issue.

Comment: Adding, residency is also not an issue - this is a dual citizen.

Comment: It's better if all the information relevant to the question appears in the question, and not in the Comments. Please add the dual-citizenship info to the question itself, using the "edit" button that appears just under the text.

Comment: There is a tax treaty between the US and Canada that will control what taxes should be paid where. See [Publication 597, Information on the United States-Canada Income Tax Treaty](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-597). I think you will have to determine where you are resident for tax purposes.